# OpenSSL/C++: can't get SNI extension to appear in ClientHello

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, sni

I'm trying to initiate a TLS connection and it must include a SNI extension.  The following program works but, despite `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` being called, does not produce a SNI record in the Client Hello packet:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main()
{
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "demo.piesocket.com:443");
    SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, "demo.piesocket.com");
    BIO_do_connect(bio);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

Yet the following command does:

```
openssl s_client demo.piesocket.com:443
```

I've checked both exchanges with Wireshark and the Client Hello packets differ only in the absence/presence of SNI.  Yes, I've looked long and hard at **s_client.c** but it does too many things and I'm new to OpenSSL and TLS.  What am I missing?

(For brevity I've removed all checks from this example code but it works, the server I'm using here doesn't seem to require SNI and the TLS connection is indeed established in both cases.  The TLS portion of the packet from **openssl.exe** looks like this:

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 319
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 315
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: 8772af2a36342435d6b73a0593087c229b67342030d23ae5…
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: 49a1e1b7eb761bd9b279efcb4cac15bae2f09bb92e641a75…
        Cipher Suites Length: 62
        Cipher Suites (31 suites)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
        Extensions Length: 180
        Extension: server_name (len=23)
        Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
        Extension: supported_groups (len=22)
        Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
        Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
        Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
        Extension: signature_algorithms (len=42)
        Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
        Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
        Extension: key_share (len=38)
```

The packet from the program doesn't have the `Extension: server_name (len=23)` line.  OpenSSL version 3.0.7, Windows 7, MinGW.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an SSL BIO via `BIO_new_ssl_connect`. This essentially creates a BIO and inside it creates a new SSL object for the connection based on the `SSL_CTX` that you pass it. Entirely separate to that you are creating a different SSL object, setting the SNI hostname on it, and then you're not using it for anything - you just free it.

Don't create a separate SSL object. Instead get hold of the SSL object inside the BIO using `BIO_get_ssl`. Set the SNI hostname on *that*.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/BIO_get_ssl.html

Comment: Wow, thanks!  While we're at it, does BIO_free_all free that automatically created SSL object?  I presume it should but what do I know. :)

Comment: Correct - yes it does.